# Python treat files with uppercase and lowercase names the same

Tags: python, file, uppercase, lowercase

I just found out this today:
If I have an existing file named a111, and I want to create a new file named A111 in the same directory with Python:

```
f = file('A111', 'w')
f.write('test')
f.close()
```

It will overwrite my file a111 and there's no A111!!
How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I believe the Mac file system is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: @MikeChristensen that's horrible :| and weird!!

Comment: Well think of the types of users Macs are designed for.  I think you can change it, but you probably have to re-format the disk.

Comment: that surprised me too, it is indeed horrible and weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not due to python.  It is due to the case-insensitivity of your underlying file system  (I'm guessing HFS+ in your case?).  From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename):

> Not all file systems in Unix-like systems are case-sensitive; by default, HFS+ in Mac OS X is case-insensitive

The solution is to use a case-sensitive file system, if you want one, or to use a different filename!

Comment: at least I know now that there's nothing wrong with my code. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This does reproduce for me, actually.

```
nixon:~ matt$ touch a111
nixon:~ matt$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov 14 2011, 19:37:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = file('A111', 'w')
>>> f.write('test')
>>> f.close()
>>> 
nixon:~ matt$ cat a111 
test
```

Also on a mac.

```
nixon:~ matt$ uname -a
Darwin nixon.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
nixon:~ matt$ python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

I suspect you'll find that what's going on is that we're both using HFS, which is a case-insensitive filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

A Mac's HFS+ filesystem is case-insensitive by default, unless you perform an installation from scratch - one of the installation options is turning on the case sensitivity.